# variable type tagged additionally with Nil in ensure clause

Tags: crystal-lang

I wonder why the type of the variable is `(String | Nil)` and not just `String`? Is there a way one can make it just `String`?

```
def main
  text = "hello"
ensure
  puts typeof(text) # => (String | Nil)
end

main
```

https://carc.in/#/r/2w3a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ensure` runs after the main body in any case, even if there was an exception raised. Because this could have happend anywhere, it has to be considered that the body of the method hasn't been executed at all if it failed at the first instruction.

Therefore, in the `ensure` block, all variables are known but it must be assumed that their value can be `nil`.

If you're sure that `text` is always set, you don't need to protect that assignment in a rescue/ensure clause.

```
def main
  text = "hello"
  begin
    # here is the code that might fail
  ensure
    puts typeof(text) # => String
  end
end
```